# C++ class members and memory position

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, memcpy, memory-alignment

I would like to copy all members of class CA in  member of class CB by using a single call to `memcpy` for performance reason.

In the basic form , I think that it is possible as they are all members of class  `CPtr` containing only pointers.

What if instead of pointers I use something like `boost::shared_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr`?

Does this idea make sense and can I get the address of &a_ and &c_, calculate the offset and do `memcpy` to &f_ ?

```
 class CBase {
   virtual ~CBase(){}
 };

 class CPtr : public CBase{
   int* p_; // what If I have shared_ptr<int> p_; ?
 };

 class CA {
 public:
    CPtr a_;
    CPtr b_;
    CPtr c_;
 };

 class CB {
 public:
    CPtr e_;
    CPtr f_;
    CPtr g_;
 };
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `CPtr` is not a POD (it has a base class with virtual functions), you cannot legally copy it via `memcpy`. Doing this is therefore a **very** bad idea.

Comment: Ok. Instead of using a memcpy can I do the following? 1. I calculate the size of a single CPtr 2. I identify the position in memory of a single CPtr in CA and CB 3. With that information I try to copy just the pointer p_ from one objecet to another. That would be more than enough for me.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile No, you are still missing the vtables.

Answer (score 0):

**There are no performance reasons to use `memcpy`.** Where `memcpy` can be used, the copy constructor will be just as efficient.

Plus the copy constructor will work in your case while `memcpy` will not. `memcpy` can only be used on "plain old data" (POD) types, which are those that only use features available in plain C plus possibly non-virtual methods. Inheritance, virtual members, constructors and destructors all make your object non-POD and you actually have all of them.